# yii set criteria params names manual

Tags: php, yii

When I set criteria:

```
$criteria->addInCondition('t.type',array_values($params[':type']));
```

I get:

```
AND (t.type IN (:ycp4, :ycp5, :ycp6))
```

I want have

```
AND (t.type IN (:type1, :type2, :type3))
```

how to generate params not automatically but set manuall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
   $params=array(':type1'=>1, ':type2'=>2, ':type3'=>3);
    $criteria->addInCondition('t.type',array_keys($params));
    $criteria->params=$params;
```

Comment: I'm getting: `(t.type IN (:ycp0, :ycp1))` I need get I'm getting: `(t.type IN (:type0, :type1))`

Answer (score 1):

you can go like this

```
$criteria->addCondition("t.Status = :stat");
```

and set the `:stat` in param

```
$criteria->params[':stat'] = 1;
```

or

```
$criteria->params = array(':stat' => 1);
```

Comment: I'm getting: `(t.type IN (:ycp0, :ycp1))`